# unity react native - which library to use for video calling in unity, wrapped as a module in react native app

Tags: react-native, unity-game-engine, video-streaming, agora.io, videocall

I am using unity for video calling but when i try to wrap this as a module in my main react native application, the app is crashing. Using agora for video calling. They dont support wrapper of wrapper.

Is there a way to implement this feature ? Sending 3d object in unity over video call, while wrapped as a module in react native

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.